# Java Web Application "Event Listener for Expired Sessions"

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there a way to run Java code, after a `HttpServletRequest Session` expired?

If a Session expires, I need to make a DB call.

Callback and Listener would be useable.

Comment: You mean like a callback or listener? Please add more details as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Now if only there would be a [component in the Servlet API for that](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

Comment: @M.Deinum Looks very useable!!!!!

Comment: I presume you revenge downvoted all my posts, since I have not interacted with anyone else on Stack Overflow today, so thank you for that. There is a script which will reverse them anyway. In future, write better questions rather than getting offended about simple requests for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`

The [*Jakarta Servlet* specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/) provides a listener interface for session expiring: [`HttpSessionListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

You write a class that implements the two methods on that interface. Mark your class with the annotation [`@WebListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) to have your class automatically instantiated by your [servlet container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container). When a session expires, the servlet container automatically invokes the [`sessionDestroyed`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed-javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent-) method on the instance of your class.

There in that [`sessionDestroyed`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed-javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent-) method, you can take any actions you want such as writing to your database.

---

The Jakarta Servlet spec provides several other such listener interfaces. You can see them listed on that [`@WebListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation’s Javadoc.

In particular, [`ServletContextListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) gives you hooks for when your web app (a “context” in servlet-speak) is launching, and when your web app is shutting down. So you can perform app-wide setup and teardown operations. Those operations would go in the two methods you write in a class implementing that interface.