# Loading a webapp (or even just a listener) from Tomcat 9 context.xml

Tags: tomcat

I have a class that I want to load and run a method once before ANY of the webapps are initialized.

Since I could not find a way to do it, I figured I could write a ServletContextListener, put it in an exploded WAR and deploy/initialize it before the other webapps.  As the other webapps are all exploded WARs and I read that I could deploy this one first by declaring it in context.xml.

Although I tried to interpret the many threads on the matter, blogs and Tomcat's docs... I clearly understood it wrong.  The main problem is that I could not find a single complete example.  I also saw references to people adding a context.xml inside of the war itself, but that seems to be for a different purpose.

This is what I did:

- I moved the listener's WAR to a folder out of webapps.
- I added the following line to Tomcat's lib/context.xml

```
<Context path="/webBootstrap" docBase="D:\work\app-j11t9-test\webBootstrap" />
```

And it made Tomcat really mad, throwing lots of errors for every single webapp.  I am sure that those in the know see what I did and roll on the floor laughing.

So, how do I do it right?
(to run that listener ONCE, before all of the other webapps initialize)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a `LifecycleListener`. The compiled code (JAR or .class in an appropriate directory structure) needs to be placed in $CATALINA_HOME/lib and you configure it in `server.xml`. There are already several such listeners defined in `server.xml` and you can look at the source of each of them for inspiration if required.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have something like a base Class? In this class you make a `static variable`.

E.g.

```java
public class BaseClass {

public static boolean initCodeRunned = false;

 public static void doInit(){
   if(!BaseClass.initCodeRunned){ 
    // Do your code

    // After the init was success, you can set the initCodeRunned to true.
    BaseClass.initCodeRunned = true;
   } 
 }
}
```

Afterward there a two ways to go on.

- First, you make in your very fist line of the index.jsp the call to the `BaseClass.init()`.
- Or you make a [SessionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62578184/11123801). In the Session Listener's `sessionCreated()`, you make the call to the `BaseClass.init()` function.

Comment: That is exactly the "band-aid" I have right now, with the listener approach... and that I am trying to replace.  The problem is that with that method I have to have the listener in every single webapp, calling the initializer at every deploy/initialize.    That is why I am wanting to place the listener in just one webapp, then make sure that the specific webapp loads first.  According to the docs any webapps declared in a context descriptor will be loaded before webapps that are simply dropped in the webapps folder.  That is what I need, but the docs are very vague.

Comment: BAND-AID solution:  I renamed the one webapp with the ServletContextListener to start with aaa, like in "aaa****".    Now I have just the one app with the listener that loads the libraries into the classloader used by all apps.  But it is an ugly hack.  I would much prefer to figure out how to properly use a Context Descriptor (in tomcat/conf/catalina/localhost/myApp.xml?) as per the original question.

Comment: There is no (easy) way to force a specific web application to be loaded first. Defining the <Context> in server.xml would do but it is strongly recommended not to do that as it means any config changes to the web app require a Tomcat restart.